# Is it bad to run ram at higher voltage?

Tags: memory, overclocking

Let me start with I know nothing about overclocking.  All I know is that my machine won't boot with all 6 ram slots full.  The ram I have is supposed to be at 1.5v but in order to even boot my system I have to have it set to 1.74v.  Is this normal??  Also am I going to damage anything by doing this?  Thanks!!!

Comment: What did you do already? Have you started overclocking? What motherboard and processor?

Comment: GA-X58A-UD3R Motherboard and i7-920.  I haven't done anything except slowing increase the ram voltage until my machine would stabilize.  I don;t want to break anything though.  I am looking for stability over performance but would like to keep all the ram for virtual machines.

Answer (score 1):

Does your RAM support XMP? If so I would try the XMP profile to see if the increased RAM bus voltage is enough to get it stable. My Asus P6X58D-E motherboard uses the XMP built into my ram to automatically apply a safe overclock. I have my 950 overclocked manually to 4ghz with a bus voltage at 1.64 all the time with no worries.